# .NET 6 - Inject service into program.cs

Tags: c#, .net, class, dependency-injection, startup

I know how to do dependency injection in the Startup.cs in .NET 5 (or before), but how do I do the same with the top-level Program.cs in .NET 6?

.NET 5: for example, I can inject a class in the Configure method

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment _env { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IToInjectService serviceToInject)
    {
        // USE SERVICE
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this in .NET 6?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using .Net 6 is easy. Just execute GetService method after configure app services and have ran Build method.

```
WebApplication? app = builder.Build();

var someService = app.Services.GetService<ISomeService>();

someService.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Any chance of getting them *before* `builder.Build()`?

Comment: I don't know if is possible

Comment: "SomeService" didn't work for me. But "ISomeService" works. In other words, use the interface with the GetService method.

Comment: Off course, "SomeService" is the interface. Is just an example, a word.

Comment: Use `SomeService` if it has no interface or if the DI registration was done without the interface. (_Why are you skipping an interface?_) Use `ISomeService` if the service was registered for DI using the interface.

Comment: A minor thing, but I'd suggest using `GetRequiredService` instead of `GetService`, or else handle the possibility of the service being null in your code.

Answer (score 18):

You add your service to the `builder.Services` collection and then access it with

```
var myService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<MyService>();
```

Comment: Maybe use `CreateScope()` to create a scope if the `MyService` is scoped.

Comment: @Tvde1 that's right

Comment: `var myService = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyService>();` if I recall correctly

Comment: @MaartenVissers that's undoubtedly answered elsewhere but it's not unimportant so just look up scoped services in your preferred search engine.

Comment: So calling BuildServiceProvider is really not recommended. It creates additional copies of singleton services.

Comment: @SaturnK where does OP say this is a singleton service?

Comment: @WimOmbelets if this is the only service that's ever going to be in the code, then yes, but this handicaps the code in case there is ever a singleton service registered in the App/API now or in the future. As I mentioned, if or more than likely, when there is a singleton service, this would create additional copies. It's an anti-pattern.

Comment: @SaturnK Be that as it may, there are situations you may find yourself in, where there simply isn't any viable alternative and, as an unfortunate side-effect of the DI implementation in .net, does cause multiple caches of singleton instances to be called into existence. AFAIK, the workarounds all point to one smell replacing another so if you have a surefire solution to this, feel free to look up the relevant questions here on SO and post your answer.

Comment: @WimOmbelets, the better solution is already answered below by @Edu_LG. You use `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` which replaces the ConfigureServices(), then you do `var application = builder.Build();` and then `var service = application.Services.GetService<T>` or `var service = application.Services.GetRequiredService<T>` and that indeed does not have a code smell.

Comment: This should not be the selected answer, as this is causing a potential further problem with dependencies being registered twice. This dependency should be retrieved from the already Built web application builder `builder.Build();`

Comment: All of the comments here including suggestions involving `builder.Build()` fail to address a situation where you need to access the injected service before calling `builder.Buid()`, e.g. when configuring another service being added to the DI container. So far, this answer is the only one I've come across that facilitates this, although I accept that it may be bad practice in the case of singleton services. If there's an alternative solution I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 16):

If you need to use a scoped service at start, this is how your **program.cs** should looks like:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Add the service
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

    var myDependency = services.GetRequiredService<IMyDependency>();

    //Use the service
    myDependency.DoSomething();

}

app.Run();
```

from:
[Resolve a service at app start up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#resolve-a-service-at-app-start-up)

it did work for mi DbInitializer

Comment: this is the real answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Inside the `program.cs` file you can manage your services by `builder.Services`

For example, I added DbContext and Two different services based on the Singleton pattern and Scoped

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    // options.UseSqlServer(...);
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMySessionBasedService, MySessionBasedService>();
```

For more information check [Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the `GetService` method but I pass the service interface type as input (as shown below) and this worked with me.

```
var app = builder.Build();    
var injectedService1 = app.Services.GetService<IToInjectService>();
injectedService1.DoSomething();
```