# Initializing Serilog with a Database Connection without Hardcoding Connection String in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I'm trying to develop a .net API as a side project and I want to add  logging functionality. From online searches, I came across the "Serilog" package and now I'm trying to implement it. But the problem is It requires a connection string to the database. As far as I know, I have to hardcode it or call it from the "appsettings.json" file. But I wanted a more secure approach.

The solution I came up with was writing a "Secret Manager" interface so later I can implement secure solutions such as "Azure Vault" but for now it is just parsing a json file to get secrets. This is my `ISecretManager` interface

```cs
public interface ISecretManager
{
    public string? GetPasswordManagerAuthDatabaseConnectionString();
    public string? GetLogDatabaseConnectionString();
    public byte[]? GetPepperSymmetricKey();
    public byte[]? GetHmacPrivateKey();
    public JwtInfo? GetJwtInfo();
    public byte[]? GetJwtKey();
    public MailInfo? GetMailInfo();
    public string GetRsaPrivateKey();
}
```

I came across a similar problem when creating my `dbContext` for my database but I was able to solve this problem in `dbContext` file.

This is my `dbContext` File.

```cs
public class AuthDbContext : DbContext
{
        private readonly ISecretManager _secretManager;
        
        public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options, ISecretManager secretManager) : base(options)
        {
            _secretManager = secretManager;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured == false)
            {
                var connectionString = _secretManager.GetPasswordManagerAuthDatabaseConnectionString();
                if (connectionString == null)
                {
                    throw new SecretNotAvailableException();
                }
                
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
            }
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ActivationCode> ActivationCodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserPassword> UserPasswords { get; set; }
}
```

I injected My secret manager into `dbContext` file and handled to configs there. But from tutorials online Serilog is created in during the builder stage and I can not use injections in this stage.

This is first half of the `Program.cs` file.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISecretManager, FileBasedSecretManager>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IJwtService, JwtService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserPasswordService, UserPasswordService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserPasswordRepository, UserPasswordRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IActivationCodeRepository, ActivationCodeRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IActivationCodeService, ActivationCodeService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICommunicationChannel, Mail>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<AuthenticationFacade>();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Host.UseSerilog(/* I need to pass connection string here */);

var app = builder.Build();
```

What is the best way to handle this? I can directly create a secret manager object but this would violate the "dependency inversion" principle and hard-coding would not be a secure approach.

Comment: You can get the service from the service collection inside `program.cs` and then use it to pass your connection string: [net-6-inject-service-into-program-cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882183/net-6-inject-service-into-program-cs)

Comment: Serilog doesn't require any connection-strings... unless you're using a database as the log-store... and I think that's a very bad idea (e.g. if your database goes down you won't get _any_ logged events...)

Comment: What would be better option for storing logs. File Based?

Comment: The best for structured logging/open telemetry would be back-end services that specialize in those.  Big and small exist:  New Relic is a big one; Seq is a small one.  If I were to be asked, I would tell you to start with small and see how it goes.  Personal Opinion Alert:  I find Seq to be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I explain in [this article](https://webjose.hashnode.dev/do-yourself-a-favor-when-writing-connection-strings-in-configuration) how you can handle connection strings not as strings, but individual pieces of information that can be individually targeted for overwriting by the .Net Configuration system.

Personally, I put the actual passwords in environment variables coming from Kubernetes secrets, but any other .Net Configuration source of your liking should work just fine.

### The Summary of the Article

1. Don't use connection strings:  Save individual properties like shown in the article (reproduced here, after this list).
2. Create a POCO class that maps to your database options.
3. Use the options pattern and inject the DB options into the service of your liking.  The article recommends creating a connection factory interface and a corresponding implementation (dependant on your actual database server technology).
4. The article shows how the factory can be used with both `Dapper` and `Entity Framework`.

Options Sample:

```json
{
  "SqlServer": {
    "Server": "my.sqlserver.enterprise.example.com",
    "Port": 1433,
    "Database": "my-db",
    "IntegratedSecurity": false,
    "Username": "sys_username",
    "Password": "undisclosed",
    "Mars": true,
    "ConnectionTimeout": "00:00:10"
  }
}
```

POCO class to inject the options to any service using `IOptions<>` (the options pattern):

```cs
public class SqlServerConnectionOptions
{
    #region Properties
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public bool IntegratedSecurity { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Mars { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? ConnectionTimeout { get; set; }
    public int? MaxPoolSize { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

MS SQL Server implementation of the connection factory that uses the options pattern:

```cs
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class SqlServerConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    #region Fields
    private Lazy<string> _connString;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public SqlServerConnectionFactory(
        IOptions<SqlServerConnectionOptions> options
    )
    {
        _connString = new Lazy<string>(() =>
        {
            var opts = options.Value;
            // We use a special string builder.
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            sb.DataSource = $"{opts.Server},{opts.Port}";
            sb.InitialCatalog = opts.Database;
            sb.IntegratedSecurity = opts.IntegratedSecurity;
            if (!opts.IntegratedSecurity)
            {
                sb.UserID = opts.Username;
                sb.Password = opts.Password;
            }
            sb.MultipleActiveResultSets = opts.Mars;
            if (opts.ConnectionTimeout.HasValue)
            {
                sb.ConnectTimeout = (int)opts.ConnectionTimeout.Value.TotalSeconds;
            }
            if (opts.MaxPoolSize.HasValue)
            {
                sb.MaxPoolSize = opts.MaxPoolSize.Value;
            }
            // Return the resulting connection string.
            return sb.ToString();
        });
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDbConnectionFactory
    public async Task<IDbConnection> CreateAsync()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new(_connString.Value);
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        return conn;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: ...or just use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`?

Comment: Good luck unit testing.